# Configure a class with a block

Tags: ruby

I have a base module that has some logic in it and it gets included inside various classes. Now I need a `configure` block that sets some configuration how the class should behave.

I tried the following code:

```
class MyConfig
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar
end

module BaseModule
  def self.included base
    base.include InstanceMethods
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :config

    def configure &block
      @config = MyConfig.new
      block.call(@config)
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def do_something
      puts self.class.config.inspect
    end
  end
end

class MyClass1
  include BaseModule

  configure do |config|
    config.foo = "foo"
  end
end

class MyClass2
  include BaseModule

  configure do |config|
    config.bar = "bar"
  end
end

MyClass1.new.do_something
#<MyConfig:0x007fa052877ea0 @foo="foo">
MyClass2.new.do_something
#<MyConfig:0x007fa052877ce8 @bar="bar">
```

> 1. I'm unsure if an instance variable `@config` for a module / class is the best way to configure a class. Is this the right way, or are there any better solutions?
> 2. Is it good to also use `base.extend ClassMethods` when the module only gets included with `include BaseModule`? A developer could expect that only instance methods get included, but as a side effect there are also class methods extended.

**Update**

I've added a `MyConfig` class, from which a new instance is created. This has the benefit that you can use `config.foo = "foo"`.

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your code a bit to use an approach both me and a lot of popular gems (like devise) use for configuration. Hope you'll like it :)

```
module BaseModule
  def self.included base
    base.include InstanceMethods
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    mattr_accessor :foo
    @@foo = 'initial value'

    def configure &block
      block.call(self)
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def do_something
      puts foo
    end
  end
end

class MyClass1
  include BaseModule

  configure do |klass|
    klass.foo = "foo"
  end
end

class MyClass2
  include BaseModule

  configure do |klass|
    klass.foo = "bar"
  end
end

MyClass1.new.do_something
# => "foo"
MyClass2.new.do_something
# => "bar"
```

The changes are:

1. use mattr_accessor - it creates both getters and setters for your method, you can opt out some of them if you wish, more info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/mattr_accessor)
2. let `configure` method return `self`, this way you can configure your class in a simple, readable, rails-like way

Example:

```
Kid.config do |k|
  k.be_kind = false
  k.munch_loudly = true
  k.age = 12
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm on sinatra, and I don't have `mattr_accessor` available. And since I don't like using class variables, I think I define a seperate config class `class MyConfig; attr_accessor :foo; end` from which a new instance is created inside `def configure &block`, assigned to `@config` and passed to the block. What do you think?